# Is it a good idea to simplify CSS by combining classes to set font families before modifying each class's other settings separately?

Tags: html, css

Apologies for the long (and possibly dumb) question. I'm not a professional website developer but I'm developing a website in my spare time for a voluntary project I'm working on with friends.

In short, instead of doing this:

```
.dlwindows {
    font-family: Minnie;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#39a3ed, #1280cf);
    width: 42.2797vh;
    color: #c4efff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #004582;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 1.464vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dlmacos {
    font-family: Minnie;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#a8b0bd, #7f8793);
    width: 42.2797vh;
    color: #fefefe;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #646672;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 1.464vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dllinux {
    font-family: Minnie;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f3aa3d, #e88d1c);
    width: 42.2797vh;
    color: #ffdb9e;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #77351a;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 1.464vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Should I be doing this?:

```
.dlwindows, .dlmacos, .dllinux {
    font-family: Minnie;
}

.dlwindows {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#39a3ed, #1280cf);
    width: 42.2797vh;
    color: #c4efff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #004582;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 1.464vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dlmacos {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#a8b0bd, #7f8793);
    width: 42.2797vh;
    color: #fefefe;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #646672;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 1.464vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dllinux {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f3aa3d, #e88d1c);
    width: 42.2797vh;
    color: #ffdb9e;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2.57998vh;
    text-shadow: 0.516vh 0.516vh 0 #77351a;
    padding: 3.096vh 3.612vh;
    margin: 1.464vh;
    font-size: 6.192vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I'm unsure - it seems like a simpler process which requires less text. Would that have any impact on my website's performance? Why or why not should I do this?

I believe I shouldn't be doing stuff like this for tags, but classes seem to be fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as "runtime efficiency", the two should be the same.

As far as "clarity", I like the idea of grouping "common elements" under a single tag.

The important thing is to make your style sheets as *LEAN* as possible.  UNCSS is a useful tool:

- https://github.com/uncss/uncss
- https://uncss-online.com/